Syntomic f-cohomology for open varieties
Syntomic cohomology $H^{i+j}_{\mathrm{syn}}(X,n)$ of a proper variety $X$ with good reduction over a $p$-adic field $K$ is computed via a spectral sequence in terms of $H^i_{\mathrm{f}}(G_K;H^j_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p)(n))$ (which is identical to the one computing $H^{i+j}_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X;\mathbb{Q}_p(n))$ except for the subscript $f$ in the Galois cohomology) - see e.g. [Niz97], [Niz01].
On the other hand, [NekNiz16] defines a version for arbitrary smooth varieties with $H^i_{\mathrm{st}}$ in place of $H^i_{\mathrm{f}}$.
But when $X$ is smooth and has a relative compactification $\overline{X}$ over $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_K}$ with relative SNC boundary $\overline{X}\setminus X$, the $G_K$-representations $H^j_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p)$ are crystalline. Thus I'm wondering: is there a version with $H^1_{\mathrm{f}}$ for such a variety?
Thus I would like essentially a version of [NekNiz16] but with $H^1_{\mathrm{f}}$ in place of $H^1_{\mathrm{st}}$. In other words, I want a theory that uses log-syntomic cohomology with log structure on the boundary in a compactification but not on the whole special fiber. The paper [Niz16] discusses the case of such a log structure but contains no discussion of descent spectral sequences.
Such a thing appears in [Niz01] and [Niz97] but only in the proper case. The latter proves some theorems about general quasi-projective varieties, but the key result I want, Corollary 3.1, is stated only for $X$ projective. (However, I don't see where the proof uses projectivity.)
(On that note, I am wondering whether Corollary 6.8 of [Bes00] is correct to allow non-proper $X$, since it cites [Niz01] (which assumes properness throughout) and [Niz97, Cor 3.1] (which also assumes properness). Another related question: should one expect the map of [Bes00, Prop 6.7] to be an isomorphism in some more generality?)
Alternatively, there is [Bann02] which has exactly what I want on the syntomic side, but with no comparison to etale cohomology. If I had, for example, a map from his spectral sequence to that of [NekNiz16] compatible with Chern classes, I would be done.
Note that [DegNiz18] claims to "generalize[] the results of Bannai", but I don't see how one gets Bannai's result from this, since [DegNiz18] uses Ext of filtered $(\varphi,N)$-modules instead of $\operatorname{Ext}$ of filtered $\varphi$-modules. This is the same as why I can't use [NekNiz16] directly for what I want.
All of the above is mainly expected when non-proper $X$ has good reduction in the strong sense, i.e., has a smooth compactification with relative SNC boundary over $V=\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_K}$, so that the geometric etale cohomology is crystalline. [Bann02] assumes this strong sense, while [Bes00] requires only a smooth model for $X$ itself. But Bloch-Kato define $H^1_{\mathrm{f}}$ even for non-crystalline representations, so one could speculate that there is a version of f-cohomology in general, even for varieties with arbitrary reduction.
Another approach would be to try to adapt [Niz01] or [Niz97] to cohomology with supports in a divisor and then take the shifted cone to get cohomology of the open complement.
[Niz97]: Niziol, Wieslawa, On the image of (p)-adic regulators, Invent. Math. 127, No. 2, 375-400 (1997). ZBL0928.14014.
[Bes00]: Besser, Amnon, Syntomic regulators and (p)-adic integration. I: Rigid syntomic regulators, Isr. J. Math. 120, Pt. B, 291-334 (2000). ZBL1001.19003.[Niz01]: Nizioł, Wiesława, Cohomology of crystalline smooth sheaves., Compos. Math. 129, No. 2, 123-147 (2001). ZBL1066.14022.
[Bann02]: Bannai, Kenichi, Syntomic cohomology as a (p)-adic absolute Hodge cohomology, Math. Z. 242, No. 3, 443-480 (2002). ZBL1053.14018.[NekNiz16]: Nekovář, Jan; Nizioł, Wiesława, Syntomic cohomology and (p)-adic regulators for varieties over (p)-adic fields, Algebra Number Theory 10, No. 8, 1695-1790 (2016). ZBL1375.14081.
[Niz16]: "On syntomic regulators I: Constructions"
[DegNiz18]: Déglise, Frédéric; Nizioł, Wiesława, On (p)-adic absolute Hodge cohomology and syntomic coefficients. I., Comment. Math. Helv. 93, No. 1, 71-131 (2018). ZBL1423.14144."On p-adic absolute Hodge cohomology and syntomic coefficients, I"

You are correct that there is a gap in the logic of Corollary 6.8 of [Bes00], since the statement is claimed without any properness condition, but the work of Niziol cited as a reference only considers the proper case. I have been told by Niziol that the gap can be fixed by using log-structures (assuming $X$ has a compactification with boundary that is a relative SNC divisor over $\mathcal{O}_K$) but I do not know if there is a published account of this.

You might also be interested in work of Ertl–Niziol which considers the relation between different versions of syntomic cohomology (with and without the special fibre included in the log-structure, so corresponding to $H^1_{\mathrm{g}}$ vs $H^1_f$ resp.).

Thanks - Ertl-Niziol does indeed fix Corollary 6.8, but there's still no corresponding spectral sequence from f-cohomology or obvious way to compare with Bannai.
